# Windows Server: can't connect to File&Print services through PPTP VPN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, pptp, windows-firewall

We have setup a simple VPN server with PPTP enabled and have forwarded correct PPTP 1723 port and GRE 47 on plain Windows Server 2008(NOT R2). Now when I am trying to connect from any VPN client ie: Windows 7 or XP it connects fine and I can PING the VPN server but I am unable to browse the remote server shared resources. When I try to access it, it always comes up with following error

"Issues found
The remote device or resource won't accept the connection
The device or resource (192.168.3.1) is not set up to accept connections on port "The File and printer sharing (SMB)"."

We have been successfully running VPN with Windows 2003 Server and Windows 2011 SBS without any issue, but only with simple Windows Server 2008 we are facing this issue.

The OS is upgraded with all the latest patches/updates and antivirus or firewalls are uninstalled also I followed the guide line here ( http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/the-device-or-resource-pc-name-is-not-set-up-to/ee29934e-7dfc-435c-ad49-7048467e465b ) to double make sure all services are running and File and Printer Sharing and Network Discovery is configured fine but still the same issue! it seems like I am stucked into a same situation like this guy is having and there was no resolution of this until upgraded to R2 http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/835347a7-b0c9-4786-9339-5b73cf0e3dcb/windows-server-2008-file-sharing-via-vpn-does-not-work

Any suggestions please?

Regards,
Faraz H. Khan

Comment: Are you able to reach other services like remote desktop or WWW? If so, check your bindings on the VPN connection item - you might have to enable file and print services there. Also, enable the [Windows Firewall log](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc947815(v=ws.10).aspx) to see if connection attempts get blocked there.

Comment: Hi, Yes all others services are forwarding fine like WWW or other. File and Print sharing is already enabled! and firewall is totally stopped from services, also as I said connection do establish fine and connect but it is shared resources which does not come via VPN on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I am not sure we have a misunderstanding here. I meant: can you reach the other services *through the VPN connection*? Also, did you install the RRAS / PPTP endpoint on the Server 2008 host exhibiting the issues? Did you use IP addresses from the same subnet which server your local Ethernet segment or did you set up another subnet with routing? Could you provide full configuration information (ipconfig /all) for the interfaces?

Comment: I don't understand the "Simple VPN" side, that's RRAS or something else?

Comment: @syneticon-dj Yes, I can connect to other services via VPN fine. The issue only occurs when I try to access shared folder via VPN.

The IP subnet is different on both location so that is not the issue.

Comment: @Noor I mean Simple VPN is that this is Windows Server VPN with PPTP and of course RRAS, nothing else.

Comment: An RRAS server can take IP addresses out of a defined pool of an already present local network (or get them from DHCP) and emulate the presence of clients via Proxy ARP. Or it can create a different, virtual network with an own, separate subnet and route the client's requests. Which one is your setup? What do IP configurations look like for your interfaces? What is the IP range the RRAS is handing out to clients? Is your PPTP VPN server *the same* server as the file&print server you are trying to access?